# Implementing std::rank for other containers

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

**Explanation :**

[std::rank](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/rank) just works for c style array .

So I implemented similar `rank` for `std::vector` which works fine :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename Type, Type val>
  struct integral_constant
  {
    static constexpr Type value =val;
  };

  template<typename>
    struct rank
    : public integral_constant<std::size_t, 0> { };

  template<typename Type>
    struct rank< std::vector<Type> >
    : public integral_constant<std::size_t, 1 + rank<Type>::value> { };

    template<class T>
   constexpr size_t vector_dimentions(T)
    {
         return rank<T>::value ;
    }

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> vec;
    std::cout<<vector_dimentions(vec) << '\n';
}
```

[ideone](https://ideone.com/UIcuFM)

**Problem :**

Now I want to generalize it for other containers like `std::list` ,...

So I change the struct definition to :

```
  template<template<typename>class Container,typename Type>
    struct rank< Container<Type> >
    : public integral_constant<std::size_t, 1 + rank<Type>::value> { };
```

[ideone](https://ideone.com/jvOkfh)

But now It gives wrong answer(always 0) !

I think in this case it can't deduce the right struct because it has now 2 template parameter . is it correct ?! How can I solve that ?

Comment: Most containers do not take exactly one template argument.

Comment: @KerrekSB I know , I think I need to use variadic templates, but using variadic template make it super complicated which is  currently beyond  my programming skills :)

Comment: I'm  surprised why in  c++14  why they just implement it for c style arrays !

Comment: I don't think it'd be super complicated (it's probably very easy), but I wonder if it's useful. You'd end up creating a trait which would treat *any* template as a container. Maybe you might like something like my `is_container` trait from the [pretty printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850473/pretty-print-c-stl-containers)?

Comment: @KerrekSB I need it for a graph libary there is a function which return number of nested nodes and types of node is a template parameter .

Comment: I would take a more careful approach and only specialize for those containers that you need. It seems too risky to just consider any template a container.

Comment: @KerrekSB this function is in a class which I check the node requirement completely with static_assert, so I don't think it cause any harms. but tnx I will keep it in mind

Comment: [A silly example. Don't use it.](http://ideone.com/mmE8nU)

Comment: @KerrekSB nice ,But it has a little problem it fails for `std::vector<std::set<std::map<std::list<int>,std::list<int>>>>>`
result should be 5

Comment: [Try this](http://ideone.com/mmE8nU)

Comment: still not working with  `using T =std::tuple<std::list<int>,std::list<int>,std::list<int>>;`

Comment: @KerrekSB [It's weird why this is not working](https://ideone.com/28blWL)

Comment: @KerrekSB wow :)) [Seems working](https://ideone.com/BaA91c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With help of [KerrekSB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/596781/kerrek-sb) I found the solution :

```
template <typename> struct prank : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 0> {};

template <template <typename...> class C, typename ...Args>
struct prank<C<Args...>>
: std::integral_constant<
    std::size_t,
    1 + prank<typename C<Args...>::value_type>::value> {};

template <typename U, typename V>
struct prank<std::pair<U, V>>
: std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 1 + prank<V>::value> {};

template <typename... Args>
struct prank<std::tuple<Args...>>
: std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 1> {};

template <typename T,typename... Args>
struct prank<std::tuple<T,Args...>>
: std::integral_constant<std::size_t, prank<T>::value+prank<std::tuple<Args...>>::value> {};
```

[ideone](https://ideone.com/mir2xr)