# How has std::rank been implemented?

Tags: c++11, std, rank

I had a look at this archive post

[Implementing std::rank for other containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24222427/implementing-stdrank-for-other-containers)

But it is still unclear to me how the logic of `std::rank` implementation works.

When I refer to the following

[std::rank](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/rank)

I see the following under **Possible Implementation**

```
template<class T>
struct rank : public std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 0> {};

template<class T>
struct rank<T[]> : public std::integral_constant<std::size_t, rank<T>::value + 1> {};

template<class T, std::size_t N>
struct rank<T[N]> : public std::integral_constant<std::size_t, rank<T>::value + 1> {};
```

Could anyone provide a simple explanation about how the above implementation logic works? (does it use variadic templates at all?)

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to explain in a simple way.

With `std::rank` you want to know the number of dimensions of an array type where a not-array is considered an array of zero dimensions.

Given a type `T`, you have three cases:

1. `T` isn't an array
2. `T` is an "array of unknown bound" (see in [this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array)) of elements of another type `U`, that is an array of unknown size, and we can express is as `U[]`, where `U` is the other type
3. `T` is an array on known size `N` of elements of type `U` and we can express it as `U[N]`, where `U` is the other type.

In cases 2 and 3 the sub-type `U` can be an array or not, so the game restart.

Look at the "possible implementation" that I have rewritten using `U` instead of `T` in cases 2 and 3

```
// case 1: T isn't an array
template<class T>
struct rank
   : public std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 0>
 { };

// case 2: T is an array of unknown bound (U[])
template<class U>
struct rank<U[]>
   : public std::integral_constant<std::size_t, rank<U>::value + 1>
 { };

// case 3: T is an array on size N (U[N])
template<class U, std::size_t N>
struct rank<U[N]>
   : public std::integral_constant<std::size_t, rank<U>::value + 1>
 { };
```

When you ask for `std::rank<T>::value` when a not-array type `T`, the only version of `rank` that matches is the first one, so the `value` is zero (inherited from `std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 0>`).

Instead, when you ask for `std::rank<T>::value` when `T` is an array type (suppose `T` is `int[3]`, so `U` is `int` and `N` is `3`) there are two version of `rank` that match `std::rank<T>`: the first one (the main, not specialized) and one of the two partial specializations). But the rules of C++ impose the compiler to choose the most specialized version, so is chose the specialized version (the third version, in case of `int[3]`) that add `1` at `std::rank<U>::value`.

A practical example

```
   std::rank<int[1][2][3]>::value
== 1 + std::rank<int[1][2]>::value
== 1 + 1 + std::rank<int[1]>::value
== 1 + 1 + 1 + std::rank<int>::value
== 1 + 1 + 1 + 0
== 3
```

Comment: I would also like to understand the implementation logic for stripping off the array dimensions in succession, in keeping with incrementing value. Can this be explained by means of a simple example?

Comment: @user9196120 - I suppose the "practical example" at the end should explain it.